# Optimal way to store statuses in DB

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I would like to have your opinion on the "best" way to manage the storage of different statuses in my DB

Currently, when I have a new status type, e.g. "status registration file", "status refund request", "status transfers to another system", I create a new table for each of these types of status, usually with an ID and a label field, then I join the created table.

I was told that this was a no-no, it was an amateur way of working, that only one table should be used, that it multiplied the tables unnecessarily and that, moreover, it was bad for performance. Less tables = more performance.

From my point of view, the advantages I find in creating one table per status type:

- allows me to add information/columns as needed (active/inactive status, additional IDs with letters or strings, descriptions, translations...), in short, information that is not necessary for most statuses.
- facilitates queries with IDEs (no need to specify the ID of the type of status to be taken into account in a query)
- ease of data retrieval with doctrine for the same reason.

The negative point:

- a table and a join to be created for each new status type.

Depending on my projects, I have 2/3 to a dozen tables to manage.

What do you think about it?
Is it bad for sql performance/cache to have many tables ( more than 100)?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

When we think of statuses we tend to either think of a series of events like 'prepared' -> 'running' -> 'finished' or of mere booleans (married = yes/no, active = yes/no). If we need this in combination with dates, we can use status history tables that show when a status changed.

But this is not what you have in mind. Your statuses come with data. When you talk about "status registration file", some registration file got involved and you want to store this with the product, order or whatever. And once you store this file (or the file's path) this implies a certain status.

Depending on what you have to store, you'll add a column or a table and maybe even a status (the registration file being unchecked, approved, dismissed).

- If I have a table of employees, I may store a column driving_licence_photo. And all employees that have a driving licince photo in the table are allowed to drive the company's cars. The status ("they have a driving licence") is implicit.
- If I have a table of employees and they can have various certificates, I may create a table employee_certificate and this table may have a certificate type, a certificate number and maybe even a status "pending" / "achieved".
- If I have a table of employees and want to know their working status ('active', 'pausing', 'retired', 'on sick leave', ...), I will probably create a table work_status and give the employee table a work_status_id.

So, the answer is: It depends.

Comment: Thank you for your response and your time. 
That's also what I'm thinking, but since I'm really not up to date, I don't know if my way of doing is still relevant.
About the number of table in databases, do you know if having a lot of table is bad for the general performance? Thanks

Comment: You can have as many tables as you want. This doesn't reduce the database performance.